# How do I change only the font size in UITabBar Item?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I change only the font size in UITabBar Item?

In my AppDelegate:

I added this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // [START initialize_firebase]
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        // [END initialize_firebase]
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


    let selectedAttr = UITabBarItem.appearance().titleTextAttributes(for: UIControlState.selected)
    let normalAttr = UITabBarItem.appearance().titleTextAttributes(for: UIControlState.normal)
    //
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: normalAttr.fontName, size: 15)!], for: UIControlState.normal)


    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: normalAttr.fontname, size: 15)!], for: UIControlState.selected)

        return true
    }
```

But I don't see any `normalAttr.fontName` property. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`titleTextAttributes(for:)` returns a dictionary which you can use to key to find the font.

```
    let normalAttr = UITabBarItem.appearance().titleTextAttributes(for: UIControlState.normal)
    let font = normalAttr[NSFontAttributeName] as! UIFont // <-- This instance has a property called `fontName`
...
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: font.fontName, size: 15)!], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much , is it also possible to get the font regardless of what controlstate?

Comment: I have an error 'Slice<Dictionary<String, Any>>' is not convertible to 'UIFont'

Comment: What version of swift are you using?

Comment: im using swift 4

Comment: can you try `normalAttr[NSFontAttributeName]`